# The most efficient way (fastest and cheapest) of working with a new TADOQuery

Tags: delphi, ado

I usually use TADOQuery with persistent fields (1 for each table), but now I find myself in a conundrum:
I have to run multiple queries at the same time (read only).

I found lots of documentation on threading. This, however, implies a newly created TADOQuery for each operation, so now I'm looking for the best way of working with them.

Like I said, I usually use persistent fields, but in this case I'm not so sure they're best, since they have to be created for each TADOQuery instance, which has a very short life.

The way I see it, I have 4 options:

```
1 - Create a MyTADOQuery class with it's own persistent fields for each table
2 - Add manually the persistent fields to each new TADOQuery
3 - ADOQuery.FieldByName('field').Value approach
4 - ADOQuery.Field[i].Value approach
```

Option 1 seems overkill(haven't actually tried it), Option 3 is slow.

My common sense tells me Option 4 is the way to go, but I have to ask:

Which of the above (or other - please do tell) is the fastest and cheapest way of working with newly created TADOQuery instances?

Thank you

Comment: 5.  Experiment with submitting multiple queries in the same batch (e.g. using a parameterised stored proc) and use the NextRecordSet method to get at the 2..Nth result sets.

Comment: @MartynA - I haven't used TADOStoredProc so far, but I'll take a look. Seems promising. TLama - Great point, thanks!

Comment: Btw, sorry, I'm assuming you're using Sql Server as your back end. If you are, you might find it easiest to start with TAdoQuery, which is happy to get multiple result sets in one go from Sql Server.  Once it's working tickety boo, put them in an SP, for tidyness's sake perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@MartynA gave a very good idea using multiple recordsets with a single `TADODataSet` by using a SP which returns multiple recordsets (Not all data providers support multiple Recordsets. This could NOT be done with MS-Access for example. since it does not support returning multiple recordsets) - You did not specify which DB you use.

With SQL Server you don't have to use a SP, and return multiple recordsets as follow:

```
qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2';
```

You need to use the ADO `qry.RecordsSet` (`_RecordSet`) directly. To move to the next recordset use `qry.NextRecordset` e.g.:

```
var
  RS: _RecordSet;

qry.Open;
RS := qry.Recordset;
repeat
  while not RS.EOF do
  begin
    for I := 0 to RS.Fields.Count - 1 do
      FieldValue := RS.Fields[I].Value;
    // or access Fields by name: RS.Fields['Field'].Value
    RS.MoveNext;
  end;
  RS := qry.NextRecordset(RecordsAffected);
until VarIsEmpty(RS);
```

This is IMHO the fastest approach.

In any case, I personally try to avoid persistent fields always.
The only case where I use persistent fields is when I need to add calculated/lookup fields to the `TDataSet`.

In that case I will dynamically populate the persistent fields (run-time) and then add the extra calculated/lookup fields dynamically.

If you wisely use `ADOQuery.FieldByName('Field')` it will not be (relatively) slow (Don't use it repeatedly inside the iteration loop - assign it to a `TField` once before you iterate the TDataSet).

`ADOQuery.Field[i].Value` is faster, but sometimes you must access the field by it's Name. It all depends on the scenario. `ADOQuery.FieldByName` is IMHO more readable and easier to maintain because you know exactly which filed you refer to.

Comment: there is still a scenario where `FieldByName` are slow: when i need to close/open the query many times for changing parameters values, rather than open once and iterat long recordset in a loop. That is a little insanity, i explicitly set `Prepared := True` yet the field objects still has to be found anew every single time...